# Execute jQuery function after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I did a function where I checked if the window has been resized and an element is visible in order to change some classes and add a little bit of css .The problem is if I refresh the page the changes are reverted . Here is a snippet of my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(window).resize(function() {
   if(isMenuVisible() == true){
     $('#my-nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
     $('#my-nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
     $('body').css('padding-top', '50px');
      } else{
      $('#my-nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
      $('#my-nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
      $('body').css('padding-top', '0');  
   }
 }) ;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  
 function resizeChanges(){
    if(isMenuVisible() == true){
       $('#my-nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
       $('#my-nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
       $('body').css('padding-top', '50px');
     }else{
       $('#my-nav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
       $('#my-nav').addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
       $('body').css('padding-top', '0');  
     }   
 }
 
 $(window).resize(resizeChanges);
 
 resizeChanges();
});
```

This way you define a separate function to make your changes, you add the event listener to trigger it but also you call that function itself after the load/refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try trigger the resize event on window after load.

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Good idea, if you put that code between `$(window).on('load', function(){ ... });`

Comment: I don't think this is necessary - http://plnkr.co/edit/8X3LtVxVNnRwp3bzjmAv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If the user refreshes the page, all changes in the client side will be lost. However, you can detect when the user refreshes the page and save the values in the server side. And then, when the page is loaded again, restore those values.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    // save the values to server side
});

$(window).on('load', function(){
    // restore values
});
```